# Switch to frames

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I nedd to switch between 2iframes using webdriver which i am unable to switch. I am able to click the 1st iframe sucessfully,but unable to switch to 2nd iframe.

### As of now i have tried the following code:

```
fd.switchTo().frame(fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/iframe[1]")));
fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[2]/img")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
fd.switchTo().frame(fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/iframe[2]")));
fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div")).click();
```

its throwing exception:

```
------------------------
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/iframe[2]"}
Command duration or timeout: 46 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminate the first iframe and try to click on the next one.

> driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

**Modified snippet here:**

```
d.switchTo().frame(fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/iframe[1]")));
fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[2]/img")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 

Thread.sleep(10000); // don't use this
fd.switchTo().frame(fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/iframe[2]")));
fd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div")).click();
```